# Please could anyone give me a generalisation of a rectangle which has a diagonal passing through it?

Tags: geometry, rectangles

[image]

Rectangles of all sorts of sizes, not just this one.

Comment: In computer graphics one would use the Bresenham algorithm for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

Consider $(p\times q)$-rectangles. Let ${\rm gcd}(p,q)=:d$. Make some drawings where $d>1$ ($d=3$ in your figure) and find out what happens.

It remains to discuss the case $d=1$. The diagonal of the $(p\times q)$-rectangle then crosses a certain total number $r$ of vertical or horizontal interior gridlines, but does not go through an interior lattice point. The number $r$ is in a simple relation with the number of squares the diagonal bisects.